# Rspec should_receive unordered checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Currently if you have a method that is called multiple times and you want to ensure that a certain call occurred then you need to write a lot of dummy code.

```
events = []
Analytics.should_receive(:track) do |event|
  events << event
end.any_number_of_times

<<INVOKE CONTROLLER ACTION>>

event = events.find{|event| event.event_name == 'MyEventName'}
event.should_not be_nil
event.properties.should include({ property_a: value})
```

The above code is needed to
1. Record all the events that were tracked
2. Find at least one instance of a certain event name and match the properties

This results in a lot of lines of code when there should be a simpler way.

```
Analytics.should_receive(:track) do |event|
  expect(event.event_name).to eq('MyEventName')
  expect(event.properties).to include({ property_a: value})
end.at_least(:once)
```

Unfortunately the above will only work if the very first call to Analytics.track results in a match. If it was the second call this test will fail.

I have my own solution to try and make it generic and reusable but I would like to know if there is a simple way to accomplish this already that I may be missing.

Comment: Your question is too complicated. Can you extract the crucial part and drop the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the exact event that you expect to `with`. The key here is stubbing `track` prior to calling `should_receive`.

Here's an example code:

```
require 'ostruct'

class Analytics
  def self.run
    track(OpenStruct.new(event_name: 'test1', properties: { a: '1' }))
    track(OpenStruct.new(event_name: 'test2', properties: { a: '2' }))
  end

  def self.track(event)
  end
end

describe Analytics do
  it 'verifies the second event' do
    expected_event = OpenStruct.new(event_name: 'test2', properties: { a: '2' })

    Analytics.stub(:track)
    Analytics.should_receive(:track).with(expected_event)

    Analytics.run
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a typo in your definition of the `track` method (`rack` vs. `track`).

Comment: Thanks, updated. I guess that method isn't even necessary, since it's being stubbed :)

Comment: Ah I did not think to stub track first.. this may be the way to go.. I will report on its success and accept if all is good

Answer (score 1):

OP should "accept" the previous answer as it contains the two key elements and came first, but here's a more succinct example (which also uses the latest `expect` approach) in case it helps to make rspec's capability clearer:

```
describe "unordered checks" do
  it 'verifies the second method call' do
    obj = Object.new
    obj.stub(:track)
    expect(obj).to receive(:track).with('expected')
    obj.track('unexpected')
    obj.track('expected')
  end
end
```

I would have edited this into the previous answer, but thought that would be taking too much license.